# in Django 1.11.6, settings.py INSTALLED_APPS not find my modules?

Tags: python, django

This is my Django settings file:

[image: settings.py]

my modules:

apps/users/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.users'
```

Error I get:

[image: error]

I scanned Django 1.11.6 doc, could not find INSTALLED_APPS change , and I don't know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: yeah, i find the reason, in pycharm, INSTALLTED_APPS write "apps.users.apps.UserConfig" is right, WTF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of write `apps.users.apps.UserConfig` is that's the direction of the class that contain the name 'apps.users' , to avoid that you can add `apps.users` inside `INSTALLED_APPS` or rename `name=users`, put `user` inside `INSTALLED_APPS`, and add this line after `BASE_DIR` var `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))`, with this in the future you wont need to include in the imports `from apps.user...` just `from user...`